# Is "set" a keyword for Java?

Tags: java, set, keyword

Beginner on Java, I got this piece of code from .java file from a big project which compiles

```
for (Var var : cfg.getArgs())
    set(var);
```

but in my Java program there is no definition of that `set` method. I am just wondering whether `set` is a keyword of Java?

Answer (score 9):

No, `set` is not a keyword in Java.

**Member function**

What you see in that snippet is a **call to a method** called `set`. Presumably a *member method* of the enclosing class, in which case it is identical to the more familiar syntax:

```
this.set(var);
```

Look above or below that particular snippet, and you'll most likely find the definition. It should look something like

```
public void set(Var var) {
    ....
}
```

**Member function of super class**

Note that it can also be a method of a **super class**. I.e., if the class is declared as

```
class Configuration extends SomeClass { ...
```

then the definition of the `set` method could be in `SomeClass`.

Here is the official list of keywords btw,

- [Java Language Keywords](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

**Statically imported method**

If it's not defined in the class, and you can't for your life find it in any super class, then it may be a statically imported method from some other class. In that case, look for something like

```
static import org.comp.Class.set;
```

in the top of the .java file.

Finally, if you're using Eclipse to develop, you can hit F4 or right click on the identifier and select declarations in project to jump to the definition of the method.

Answer (score 2):

`set` is likely the name of another method in the Java code you borrowed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords), no set isn't a keyword: